# SQL: no such table error

Tags: python, sql, pycharm

В Python пытаюсь спарсить таблицу в SQL. Название первого столбца парсит, а дальше не идёт. И БД, и документ, и скрипт - всё лежит в одной папке, но вот таблицу в БД почему-то не видит.

```
    sql = 'INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})'.format( 
                db_table_name,
                ','.join(data),
                ','.join(['?']*len(data)))
                cur.execute(sql, tuple(data.values()))
                con.commit()
                column_num += 1
```

Ошибка:

```
 File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\main.py", line 64, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql, tuple(data.values()))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: 'hae'
```

Comment: А у вас существует таблица **hae**? Можете посмотреть, какой SQL запрос отправляется в БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в итоговый запрос имя таблицы в которую вы что - то инсертите вставляется значение переменной `db_table_name`. Судя по тексту ошибки в этой переменной находится значение hae. Если это то, что вас нужно, то значит вам нужно сначала создать эту таблицу, через `CREATE TABLE`. Если название таблицы должно быть другим, то отслеживайте значение переменной `db_table_name`, видимо туда что-то левое попадает.